# Rebind Jquery Autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I want to rebind the auto-complete plugin on its select event, actually I want to remove the selected item from suggestion. Currently the code is like what is pasted below, if I copy the whole plugin call in select function, that would be nonsense as I would have to paste that in the copied call's select event too and so on. Is there any other simple way?

```
$("#txtEmployeeID").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");

                var matching = $.grep(newEmployeesWithIds, function (value) {
                    var name = value.value;
                    var id = value.id;

                    return matcher.test(name) || matcher.test(id);
                });
                response(matching);
            },
            select: function (event, value) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET", //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
                    url: "http://localhost:46455/EmployeeSearchService.svc/GetEmployee", // Location of the service
                    data: {
                        "name": value.item.value
                    }, //Data sent to server
                    dataType: "Json", //Expected data format from server
                    processdata: "false", //True or False
                    success: function (employee) {//On Successfull service call
                        //INSERTING THE SELECTED OBJECT IN A UL
                        var employee = $.parseJSON(employee);
                        $('#ulSelectedEmployees').append($('<li>').attr('id', employee.TRGEmpID).css('padding', '5px').attr('class', 'ui-menu-item').html(employee.FullName).append($('<img>').attr('src', 'Styles/images/close_icon.png').attr('height', '20px').css('float', 'right').css('padding', '2px 13px')));
                        if ($('#ulSelectedEmployees').css('display') == 'none')
                        {
                            $('#ulSelectedEmployees').show();
                            $('#' + employee.TRGEmpID).fadeIn(700);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $('#' + employee.TRGEmpID).fadeIn(700);
                        }
                        /*DELETING THE ELEMENT TO REBIND AUTOCOMPLETE*/
                        for(var k = 0 ; k < newEmployeesWithIds.length ; k ++)
                        {
                            if(newEmployeesWithIds[k].id == employee.TRGEmpID)
                                break;
                        }

                        newEmployeesWithIds.splice(k, 1);
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {//On UnSuccessfull service call
                        ServiceFailed(msg);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Deleting the element from the source array like you're doing should work fine. What exactly is the problem? Why would you need to re-bind the entire widget?

Comment: but the item is appearing in the suggestions even after removing. I debugged the script, and item is removing just fine, but still it appears in suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure you're not searching again before the AJAX request finishes? A simple example seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Aa5nK/10/